# Angular error while checking if URL response is "success"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, httprequest

I have this code that is requesting external URL to check if it is returning with success status(URL is reached and not corupted):

```
$http.get($scope.linkAnswer).then(function () {
                        linkStatus = true;
                        console.log("veikia");
                    }, function () {
                        linkStatus = false;
                        console.log("neveikia");
                    });
```

However I am getting this error when requesting:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load REQUESTED URL. No **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'** header is present on the requested resource. Origin **'MY LOCALHOST URL'** is therefore not allowed access.*

Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: What does `$scope.linkAnswer` refer to?

Comment: Google "CORS".. Btw, it's much faster to find answer in google then posting the question.

Comment: Asking a question here can be helpful since the answers can be clearer + you don't need to scour for the web for the exact solution, especially difficult if you have no idea what's happening at all.

Comment: $scope.linkAnswer - string that contains URL.

Comment: @Fissio: really ? "no idea what's happening at all" when you have the error message saying: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load REQUESTED URL. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. " ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a domain different than the one that initially served you request. This is not allowed, because other domain usually protects its resources for internal use only.

So, i can conclude that **$scope.linkAnswer** contains url **different** from you domain.
You have to allow access using ***CORS*** (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)

What is value in $scope.linkAnswer?